# xpages combobox control where user can enter values not in list

Tags: xpages

I need to create a comboBox control that displays a list of values but allowas the user to enter a value not in the list. I saw where you can do this with dijit.form.comboBox but I understand that no longer works after 8.5 something. So that route is out. This should be pretty basic and I'm guessing that I'm just missing a property somewhere.
Any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why should diji.form.comboBox not work? Maby you forgot Setting dojoForm="true" dojoTheme="true" dojoParseOnLoad="true" or to add the dojoModule Name="dijit.form.ComboBox" as resource to your XPage.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example for core control `xp:comboBox` where users can enter values not in list *without* using Extension Library:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dijit.form.ComboBox"
            rendered="true">
        </xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:comboBox
        id="comboBox1"
        value="#{sessionScope.Test}"
        dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox"
        disableValidators="true">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="abc"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="def"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="xyz"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:comboBox>

    <xp:button
        value="Submit"
        id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete"
            immediate="false"
            save="true">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Three things are important here:

1. Add dojoModule ressource `dijit.form.ComboBox`
2. Add `dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox"`
3. Add `disableValidators="true"` otherwise new values not in list won't get submitted.

If you are allowed to use Extension Library in your project then you would use Dojo Form control "Dojo Combo Box" `xe:djComboBox` of course instead.

Comment: In the end I did use the djComboBox and it is working fine, but I guess my N/D background keeps coming to the fore. I would think that this should be a property of a basic combo box just like in Note. "Allow Value Not in List" true/false. Yes, it is there in the djComboBox, and yes you can program around it, but.... Why?

Comment: The reason for not being in standard is probably because it's not supported by standard HTML. HTML's `<select>` tag doesn't support "new values". Only add-ons like Dojo are capable to deliver this functionality. But, with Extlib, UP1 and standard version 9 we have djComboBox which gives the "new values" functionality out of the box. - I gave this example for projects where ExtLib is not allowed like a project I am on right now.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed today, thank you @KnutHerrmann !!! (I see it now in the ext lib, duh.  Its Friday afternoon here :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it with a djComboBox wish it were property of the core control.

Comment: Isn't it in the Extlib?